# My Jar file not working properly as project works in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

My project works perfectly in IntelliJ IDEA but not working properly as a executable JAR file. It is missing some of my code.. My project is connected to mySQL database. It gives no error.. I have created Jar file with Artifacts. with module with dependencies. Please answer I'm beginner. Thanks

Comment: What is the error? Please attach the stack trace for better clarity.

Comment: Looks like the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43530285/104891).

Comment: There is no error in IDE.. When I deploy Jar file to another PC. It only shows main Screen and when I head to Login Page, application crashed. I think it is due to Database. Because there is no manager is installed on another PC... Please help to deploy application with database (mySQL).. Thanks.